# Question about the stationary point

Tags: calculus

Suppose $x_0$ is a stationary point of $f(x)$ and $x_0$ is not a local extremum. Does this implie $x_0$ is an inflection point?

Here I notice that the second derivative $f''(x_0)$ may not exist,so we cannot use the second derivative test to do this. What is the possible approach to this question?

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(0) = 0,$ otherwise $$ f(x) = x^3 \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)  $$ so that the function satisfies $f(-x) = f(x).$